# extracting location specific record using sed based on given criteria using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to extract data from a ASCII file that looks like the one provided here  the block starting 1NAME. The block starting 1NAME can repeat any number of times - I have files where there is only one block and in some files as many as  744:

```
AVERAGE   MODELNAME -- RUNNAME
 0  1  11121    0. 11122   24.
       -9700000         4000000   0   -241200000000   -1620000
1.00000      1000.00000  10 10   1   2   0    15.    11.     0.
    1    1  500  400
NAME
          11121      0.00     11121      1.00
   1NAME
 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00
 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00
 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00 0.0000000E+00
NAME
          11121      1.00     11121      2.00
   1NAME
 1.0000000E+00 45.0000000E+00 01.0000000E+00 115.0000000E+00 5.0000000E+00
 2.0000000E+00 66.0000000E+00 09.0000000E+00 180.0000000E+00 4.0000000E+00
 3.0000000E+00 80.0000000E+00 70.0000000E+00 130.0000000E+00 5.0000000E+00
```

I would like to extract values from  (1) given recurring location in the file, starting after "1NAME", (2) pipe outputs to a text file and create header that identifies what location it was pulled from and (3) create a custom code that can take in input for multiple locations (say record 1, 5, 8) after 1NAME and output them into separate outputs (example: one output for all records at location 1, one output file for location 5, ...).

As an example say I want to grab record 1, 5 and 8 after 1NAME in the given input file. Outputs for each record should be output as follows in separate record specific text file  labeled as GRID#.txt:

```
GRID 1    
0.0000000E+00
00.0000000E+00
GRID 5
0.0000000E+00
5.0000000E+00
GRID 8
0.0000000E+00
09.0000000E+00
```

I was able to extract data on at a time using sed. However I need to extract data from multiple locations from the input file. So I tried to put all the information in a script. Following are the steps I took.

1. Input file has multiple whitespaces and inconsistent blank lines. So I used sed to remove multiple spaces and replace with one space. And then using the piped output from this step, removed all blank lines. This resulted in all the data in the file arranged as one value per row.

   ```
   sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' <input.txt>| sed '/^$/d
   ```
2. To extract data, I then used sed command (format as follows) from piped output from step 1.

   ```
   sed -n -e 11p -e 50p
   ```
3. I tried to put all these commands as a bash (or csh, either option) script with custom row number. I tried using foreach (naively) and then learned that it cannot be used within bash. I will be using fellow user recommended scripts instead.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash 
   set FILE=$cwd/sample_or_2day
   foreach GRID (23729)
   foreach GRIDTIME(28 41)
   sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' $FILE | sed '/^$/d' | sed '1,36d' > temp_out
   sed -n -e "$GRIDTIME" temp_out | tee $cwd/out_$GRID
   ```

Thanks for your patience. I am a nervous programmer and trying to master basics. I spent time looking at sed instruction pages, and user support forums. Any recommendations are welcome - especially with explicit instructions. Thanks!

Comment: Given the input above, which output do you want?

Comment: I have updated the format of the input and output file and formatted code under #3

Comment: `foreach` doesn’t exist in `bash`. It’s `for`, not `foreach`, and it supports two different syntaxes, both quite different from the one you are using. `help for` will show you both.

Comment: Noted, would foreach work with csh? I was unable to interpret the help page well.

Comment: If you are asking about `csh` and not `bash` (a completely different language), tag your question accordingly. The syntax you are using for loops is indeed from `csh`, but it lacks the `end` statements to close the repeating blocks. There is no good reason to use `csh` in the 21st century

Comment: Dario, I have no preference between bash or csh. I have worked with prewritten scripts in both shells before, but never wrote one from scratch myself. If I had to stick to bash, how can I modify and update the mentioned code? Sorry if my question seems rather trivial, but as a new user, I feel overwhelmed with interpreting the multiple resources I consulted.

Comment: [I would recommend you establish a preference between bash and csh](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html). Also, when handing input with clear records, consider **[tag:awk]**, which was built for that kind of processing.

Answer (score 0):

You provided your attempt at a `csh` script, but tagged your question as `bash`. I am answering with a `bash` script.

The core of your question is how to extract information from a formatted printout. In general, one should avoid such situations: one should use programming environments which are aware of the data structures being manipulated, in order to avoid re-parsing at each step. In the real world, however, such situations arise very often, and one has to cope with them.

Your approach to transform all white spaces into newlines works in your case. Instead of multiple `sed` commands, the fastest way to achieve it is by

```
tr -s ' ' '\n'
```

(the `-s` option squeezes multiple occurrences of the target character into one, eliminating blank lines)

Then, you are interested in the 7th and 14th lines after each occurrence of a line containing `1NAME`. This is done in `sed` by

```
sed -n -e '/^1NAME$/{n;n;n;n;n;n;n;p;n;n;n;n;n;n;n;p}'
```

which means: *when you see 1NAME, execute the **n**extline command seven times, then execute the **p**rint command. Do this twice.*

You could use a shell variable:

```
next7='n;n;n;n;n;n;n;p'
```

And

```
cat ./sample_or_2day | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -n -e '/^1NAME$/'"{$next7;$next7}"
```

would produce

```
0.0000000E+00
0.0000000E+00
66.0000000E+00
130.0000000E+00
```

correct, the first block was also taken in. To skip it, let’s add the `sed` instruction you had already figured out, `-e1,36d`.

```
$ cat ./sample_or_2day | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -n -e1,36d -e'/^1NAME$/'"{$next7;$next7}"
66.0000000E+00
130.0000000E+00
```

You might also want `bash` to construct the `sed` command line for you: for instance, the command

```
sed -n -e{7..29..7}p
```

would be expanded by the shell as

```
sed -n -e7p -e14p -e21p -e28p
```

which, as you know, means that `sed` would print those input lines only.
You might also want to learn about `for` loops in `bash`, which come in two different flavors, for example:

```
for var in word1 word2 word3 ...; do ... ; done
for (( i=0; i<10; i++ )); do ...; done
```

Now, it is not clear to me how you want to manage your output files. I provide a `bash` version of your script (providing a list of values for GRID, instead of just one), which shows another possible brace expansion in `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=./sample_or_2day
for GRID in 23729 23755 23768; do
  cat "$FILE" | tr -s ' ' '\n' | sed -n -e{28,41}p >> "./out_$GRID"
done
```

Comment: Dario, Thanks a lot - this is so much clearer. Unfortunately, I cannot do much about the formatting of the output, because it comes in this format from a complex environmental model. I want the output file to be a txt or a csv file that I can manipulate later in Excel. Also as you pointed out, GRID can take more than one value. I added just one to first figure out a basic form of the code. If I have multiple inputs for GRID, how can include that?

Comment: @learning_to_code Edited to show how to have multiple inputs for GRID. You should accept the answer if you are pleased with it.

Comment: I realized while testing the script, that it did not do exactly what I was thinking of - and I phrased my question about multiple inputs to GRID incorrectly. What I would like is for each input of GRID, the record value be unique. As an example for GRID 23729, in the bash script, we choose record on line 7 after 1NH3. Then for say the next GRID 23755, we would like to choose line 100 after 1NH3. And have outputs for GRID(s) 23729 and 23755 in separate files. How can that be applied in the bash script?

Comment: Please edit the question specifying this requirement clearly and also specifying which rule permits to compute the line number on the basis of the GRID value. If it is only a table with two columns (GRID, line_to_extract) stored somewhere and no way to compute, it’s fine, but it must be specified in the question. The present version already sends the output for different GRIDs to separate files.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: The above codes are not returning an value. Any output file I am piping results to are also empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me so far, but not as a bash script:

```
sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' ./sample_or_2day | sed '/^$/d' | sed '1,36d'| sed -n -e{23724..194842..97421}p > './out'
```

In the above script:

- sed 's/\s+/\n/g' -> replaces multiple whitespaces with one space
- sed '/^$/d' ->  deletes blank line from piped output
- sed '1,36d' ->    removes line 1-36 from piped output
- sed -n -e{23724..194842..97421}p    -> prints record starting line
  23724 and at intervals of 97421, until line 194842
- './out' -> outputs to file labeled out

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to adding a python dependency, you may find this'll help:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/context-split.html

Or try awk, replacing /^BEGIN/ and /^END/ with your own regex's:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
BEGIN { show=0 }
/^END/ { show=0 }
{ if (show==1) print $0 }
/^BEGIN/ { show=1 }' $@
```

Comment: Hi dstromberg: Could you be more explicit about using awk for my case? It is unclear how I can substitute the show=0 part with expression that would work here.